# Ошибка в библиотеке?

Tags: rust

Пытаюсь забилдить [джарвиса](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzL9BY1D2L0&t=255s), и получаю эти ошибки

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound BundleResources: Default is not satisfied
    --> C:\Users\RimYT.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tauri-build-1.3.0\src\lib.rs:330:61
     |
330  |   let mut resources = config.tauri.bundle.resources.clone().unwrap_or_default();
     |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait Default is not implemented for BundleResources
     |
note: required by a bound in std::option::Option::<T>::unwrap_or_default
    --> C:\Users\RimYT.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\option.rs:1006:12
     |
1004 |     pub fn unwrap_or_default(self) -> T
     |            ----------------- required by a bound in this associated function
1005 |     where
1006 |         T: Default,
     |            ^^^^^^^ required by this bound in Option::<T>::unwrap_or_default
error[E0599]: no method named as_slice found for enum BundleResources in the current scope
    --> C:\Users\RimYT.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tauri-build-1.3.0\src\lib.rs:338:47
     |
338  |   copy_resources(ResourcePaths::new(resources.as_slice(), true), target_dir)?;
     |                                               ^^^^^^^^ method not found in BundleResources
     |
note: the method as_slice exists on the type Vec<std::string::String>
    --> C:\Users\RimYT.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\alloc\src\vec\mod.rs:1188:5
     |
1188 |     pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Дело в библиотеке?